# Remote access to Sharepoint Service 3.0 Intranet

Tags: sharepoint, remote-access, intranet, sharepoint-services

I'm working on my companies Intranet via Sharepoint Service 3.0 but I'm having quite some difficulties trying to "open" the Intranet to remote or external access via a browser.

It is important because not every employee is located within the local network area and they have to be able to get access when on business trips and more.

I've tried to scout Google for a solution but everything I've tried so far has not given any result. I thought I got it today but now it seems to get a timeout when trying to connect via the URL: 
https://remote.ourdomain.com:port/

Please ask if you need some additional information

Sincerely
Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/11/04/sharepoint-2007-farm-ports-configuring-firewall.aspx) should help get you going

By default the ports required on the client side are port 80 and 443.  If you have configured additional sites on additional ports (and by your example it looks like you did) then the additional ports also need to be opened.  Have you verified that the URL works on the local lan?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the link. I'm a little confused about what to do with all the information but will screen the page again.  
Yes I tested the URL and verified that it worked on our local lan and on our wireless connection. Everything checked out.

Comment: What questions do you have about the link provided?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to add a port forwarding rule to your firewall for either port 80 or port 443 or both depending on how your share point is set up.

Here are some questions you need to answer:

Does your company have a static IP address?
Does your company host any other web sites from that IP address?

You will also need to look at alternate access mapping:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100618063935/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/06/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1.aspx)

And since you are publishing this to the web, you will need an SSL certificate. It's not required, but you should use one. I got mine cheap from GoDaddy.

As Jim B mentioned, a lot of what you need to do will deppend on exactly how you have WSS configured.